# Callout from end of text

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am trying to put a callout at the end of a line of text. The minimal example is below; the full example has multiple lines of code that are revealed in overlays and I want to have a callout at the right side of each line of code with some comments. The result is shown below; as you will see the callout is not positioned to the right of the text, but on th ene. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}

\texttt{\footnotesize{
lines = spark.textFile(“hdfs://...”)} \tikz[na] \coordinate (anc1);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}{>=stealth,overlay,show background grid}

%\coordinate[right=2cm of anc1] (anc2);
%\draw[-] (anc1.north east) -- (anc2);
\node[rectangle callout,draw,inner sep=2pt,color=blue,fill=blue,text=white,align=left,
      callout absolute pointer=(anc1.north east),
      above right= 15pt and 0pt of anc1.north east]
      {\footnotesize CreateRDD};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** I have used `tikzmark` as recommended. And removing the line before `\begin{tikzpicture}` certainly solves that problem. However, as I noted earlier, I have multiple lines of this text and when I use `\\` or `\newline` to break the lines, I have the same problem. I guess I should have posted with multiple lines originally -- my MWE was too minimal. The new code and the resulting output are below. Any help would be appreciated...

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,positioning,tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}

\texttt{\footnotesize{
lines = spark.textFile(“hdfs://...”)} \tikzmark{anc1} \\ %\tikz[na] \coordinate (anc1);
errors = lines.\textcolor{blue}{filter}(\alert{\_.startsWith(“ERROR”)})  tikzmark{anc2}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}{>=stealth,overlay,show background grid}

\node[rectangle callout,draw,inner sep=2pt,color=blue,fill=blue,text=white,align=left,
      callout absolute pointer=(pic cs:anc1.north east),
      above right= 15pt and 0pt of pic cs:anc1.north east]
      {\footnotesize CreateRDD};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: just delete the blanck line befor tikzpicture

Comment: I might use `\tikz` instead of the environment, but you are certainly putting an explicit paragraph between your text and your picture with those blank lines....

Comment: Take a look at `tikzmark` - it will make things easier.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the main problem is not with tikzmark, it is woth the options for `tikzpicture`. Use `\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,overlay,show background grid]`
 and not `\begin{tikzpicture}{>=stealth,overlay,show background grid}`

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I don't really see the problem. You put the marks where you want the anchors and then you add the callouts later. I've included an example with 2 callouts on each of 2 slides and I've just updated to apply my answer to your current MWE. You can add whatever line breaks you like between the lines of code. There is simply no problem with this. Just make sure that you issue `\callout{}{}` or `\tikzmark{}` *before* the line break if you want the callout to occur on the current line. Then create a `tikzpicture` or issue `\makecallouts` after setting all your callout locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you had braces and not brackets for the `tikzpicture` options, so they were ignored:

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}

\texttt{\footnotesize{
lines = spark.textFile(“hdfs://...”)} \tikz[na] \coordinate (anc1);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,overlay,show background grid]

%\coordinate[right=2cm of anc1] (anc2);
%\draw[-] (anc1.north east) -- (anc2);
\node[rectangle callout,draw,inner sep=2pt,color=blue,fill=blue,text=white,align=left,
      callout absolute pointer=(anc1.north east),
      above right= 15pt and 0pt of anc1.north east]
      {\footnotesize CreateRDD};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'd suggest you to use the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library to place a mark to be used later to place the callout:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer} %
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,positioning,tikzmark}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\footnotesize
  columns=fullflexible,
  breaklines=true
}

\tikzset{
  %every picture/.append style={remember picture},
 na/.style={baseline=-.5ex}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}

{\ttfamily\footnotesize
lines = spark.textFile(“hdfs://...”)\tikzmark{anc1} \par
errors = lines.\textcolor{blue}{filter}(\alert{\_.startsWith(“ERROR”)})\tikzmark{anc2}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,remember picture,overlay,show background grid]
\node[rectangle callout,draw,inner sep=2pt,color=red,fill=red!30,text=black,align=left,
      callout absolute pointer=({pic cs:anc1}),
      above right= 25pt and 0pt of {pic cs:anc1}]
      {\footnotesize CreateRDD};
\node[rectangle callout,draw,inner sep=2pt,color=blue,fill=blue,text=white,align=left,
      callout absolute pointer=({pic cs:anc2}),
      above right= 15pt and 40pt of {pic cs:anc2}]
      {\footnotesize CreateRDD};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Notice that it's best to use `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle`. Also, \footnotesize (and similar) are switches, not commands with arguments, so they are to be used as in `{\footnotesize text}` or `{\footnotesize text\par}` for long texts.